# Insert condition into a nested IIf

Tags: vba, reporting-services

Visual Basic is used to generate reports in SSRS.

I'm trying to alter a report that pulls client information. I want to check the record for a secondary address, if they do not want to display their primary address. The SQL query is working right and is pulling all the relevant data.

The information is displayed using Visual Basic which I know even less about than I do sql. I managed to get the relevant data to display correctly except for the "line 2" section of the address.

An image of the section.

[image]

"Address Line 2" is what I'm trying to fix.

The expression from the original version:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!AccountBillToLine1.Value), IIf(IsNothing(Fields!ContactBillToLine1.Value), IIf(IsNothing(Fields!AccountLine2.Value), IIf(IsNothing(Fields!ContactLine2.Value), "", chr(13)+chr(10)+Fields!ContactLine2.Value), chr(13)+chr(10)+Fields!AccountLine2.Value), IIf(IsNothing(Fields!ContactBillToLine2.Value), "", chr(13)+chr(10)+Fields!ContactBillToLine2.Value)), IIf(IsNothing(Fields!AccountBillToLine2.Value), "", chr(13)+chr(10)+Fields!AccountBillToLine2.Value))
```

I'm trying to insert into this cluster a condition to also check "SecondaryAddressLine2" and if it contains information to display it below "Address Line 1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps with readability if you format it with indents so that the closing parentheses line up with the "IIf" statements.

```
=
IIf(IsNothing(Fields!AccountBillToLine1.Value), 
 IIf(IsNothing(Fields!ContactBillToLine1.Value), 
  IIf(IsNothing(Fields!AccountLine2.Value), 
   IIf(IsNothing(Fields!ContactLine2.Value), "", chr(13)+chr(10)+Fields!ContactLine2.Value
   ), chr(13)+chr(10)+Fields!AccountLine2.Value
  ), IIf(IsNothing(Fields!ContactBillToLine2.Value), "", chr(13)+chr(10)+Fields!ContactBillToLine2.Value
     )
 ), IIf(IsNothing(Fields!AccountBillToLine2.Value), "", chr(13)+chr(10)+Fields!AccountBillToLine2.Value
    )
)
```

This is still difficult to understand. You may want to consider rewriting it using a `Switch` statement so that the conditions and results match up more nicely and there's no nesting. To answer you question though, you can wrap the whole thing in another `IIf` to add your condition like this:

```
=
IIF(IsNothing(Fields!SecondaryAddressLine2.Value),
 IIf(IsNothing(Fields!AccountBillToLine1.Value), 
  IIf(IsNothing(Fields!ContactBillToLine1.Value), 
   IIf(IsNothing(Fields!AccountLine2.Value), 
    IIf(IsNothing(Fields!ContactLine2.Value), "", chr(13)+chr(10)+Fields!ContactLine2.Value
    ), chr(13)+chr(10)+Fields!AccountLine2.Value
   ), IIf(IsNothing(Fields!ContactBillToLine2.Value), "", chr(13)+chr(10)+Fields!ContactBillToLine2.Value
      )
  ), IIf(IsNothing(Fields!AccountBillToLine2.Value), "", chr(13)+chr(10)+Fields!AccountBillToLine2.Value
     )
 ) , chr(13)+chr(10)+Fields!SecondaryAddressLine2.Value)
)
```

The `chr(13)+chr(10)` there just inserts a new line, but you can also use `VbCrLf` which is more standard.

Comment: Thanks so much Steven!  I was trying to nest it in the middle but your solution worked so much better.  Initially I was getting an end statement expected error and ran it through notepad++ and found the last parentheses was superfluous.